# Source for generating people data?

Tags: testing, test-data

This is only tangentially a programming question. Where can I find a simple-to-parse list of people names? This is really just filler material, so they don't need much rhyme or reason.

Alternatively, is there a programmer's equivalent to [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) for when you need to create a bunch of dummy accounts?

Comment: Edited to hopefully avoid quick closure. Hint for the future - step back to the technical impetus for the question to ensure you get the best quality answers, and avoid getting shut down right away.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Rex M! That is really is a MUCH better title for what my question ultimately is. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw names randomly from [names.txt](http://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt) (46 KiB, comma-separated values) from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problem 22.

---

**EDIT**: The [U.S. Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov) has [statistical data for first and last names](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.generatedata.com

Benjamin Keen has created this terrific tool that would probably fit the bill for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a bunch of names and numbers:

```
firsts = [ "Dave", "John", "Jane", "Jack", ...];
seconds = [ "McMuffin", "Frontage", "Bush", "McProgrammer", ...];

for f in firsts {
    for s in seconds {
        for( i=0; i<10; i++){
            tmp_user = f + "_" + s + i;
            // Add user to database
        }
    }
}
```

That's quite alot of usernames if you add a few more :)

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

If you just need some text and dont care how it looks, you could use something like Excel to generate a big list of names.

eg: in cell A1 enter **="FirstName" & ROW(A1)** then select however many rows you want and fill down. In column B do the same for surname, save as CSV and import into your DB.

Or you could get a little smarter: Put some first names in column A and some surnames in column B.

Formula for C1:

```
=OFFSET(A$1,INT(RAND()*[[number_of_first_names]]),0)
```

and something similar for D1:

```
=OFFSET(B$1,INT(RAND()*[[number_of_last_names]]),0)
```